# Does the color/brightness of a dot on the ground mean anything?

Tags: brogue

I know that a <kbd>.</kbd> is bare ground - as opposed to the green flora <kbd>"</kbd> etc... but I also notice that a <kbd>.</kbd> comes in many different shades of gray. Those shades of gray don't directly correlate to the "blueness" of the square they're in - and that blue background color definitely represents the tile's ambient light and thus my chance of being spotted. What, then, does the whiteness level of the <kbd>.</kbd> mean?

Comment: "that blue background color definitely represents the tile's ambient light and thus my chance of being spotted" - sort of. The tile background is somewhat related to the ambient light, but it's not deterministic. To be certain you need to look at the @ color - blue is super-dark, white (/ light blue) is dark, yellow is light.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything, it's just aesthetic.